# Narrowing down error type in catch

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

For this piece of code

```
try {
  throw new CustomError();
}
catch (err) {
  console.log(err.aPropThatDoesNotExistInCustomError);
}
```

`err` is `any` and doesn't trigger type errors. How can it be narrowed down to the type that error is expected to be?

Comment: **See Also**: [How do you use typed errors in async catch()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42618089/1366033)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You need to perform a check yourself to narrow inside a catch block. The compiler does not know or believe that `err` will definitely be a `CustomError`:

```
try {
  throw new CustomError();
}
catch (err) {
  console.log('bing');
  if (err instanceof CustomError) {
    console.log(err.aPropThatIndeedExistsInCustomError); //works
    console.log(err.aPropThatDoesNotExistInCustomError); //error as expected
  } else {
    console.log(err); // this could still happen
  }
}
```

For example, here's my evil implementation of `CustomError`:

```
class CustomError extends Error {
  constructor() {
    super()
    throw new Error('Not so fast!');  // The evil part is here
  }
  aPropThatIndeedExistsInCustomError: string;
}
```

In this case `err` will *not* be a `CustomError`.  I know, that's probably not going to happen, but the point is that the compiler won't do this narrowing automatically for you.  If you are absolutely sure of the type, you can assign to another variable:

```
try {
  throw new CustomError();
}
catch (_err) {
  const err: CustomError = _err;
  console.log(err.aPropThatDoesNotExistInCustomError); // errors as desired
}
```

but remember that you could possibly run into trouble at runtime if you're mistaken about the type.

Good luck!

P.S.: See TypeScript issues [#8677](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8677) and [#9999](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9999) for more information.

Comment: Thanks. `instanceof` is not an issue here, error type is unambiguous, moreover it's `CustomError` type, not necessarily an instance. `const err: CustomError = _err` looks like a really ugly hack. I've checked #8677 and #9999, and it looks like they were closed via PR, but I'm not sure how PR solved the problem,

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about `instanceof`.  If you do `throw new CustomError()` you have created (and thrown) a new instance of the `CustomError` class.  The check `err instanceof CustomError` will return `true` if and only if `err`'s constructor is `CustomError` constructor.

Comment: It used to be that you couldn't even narrow with `instanceof` or other type guards (so you pretty much *had* to assign the caught object to a new narrowed variable), but #9999 fixed that part of it.

Comment: In this example it surely is. In any other case it can be a function that throws an error with CustomError interface (that's what `err: CustomError` implies). Thanks for the notice, I noticed that `instanceof` started to affect types at some point in a positive way but wasn't sure where this change came from.

Comment: As for the ugliness/hackiness of introducing a new variable: it's unfortunately the most straightforward way for you to force the compiler to assume the error is of the type you think it is.  You can't annotate the type of the caught object; all you can do is narrow it with type guards or assign it to a new variable.  If someone can suggest a cleaner answer, I'd be interested but surprised to hear it.  From reading #8677 and #9999, this is as good as it gets.

Comment: I guess that's true, at least until there will be `catch(err: CustomError)`. `instanceof` type guard is nice but the consequences may be really bad if the error won't be an instance while it is supposed to be (e.g. because of duped NPM packages). Thanks for the answer.