# What is the correct jsdoc type annotation for a try..catch identifier?

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-closure-compiler, jsdoc

**When annotating JavaScript sources with JSDoc comments, how do you annotate the type of the try..catch identifier?**

```js
try {
  throw new Error();
} catch (whatIsMyType) {
  console.error(whatIsMyType.message);
}
```

I'm specifically asking for the [TypeScript JSDoc dialect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html), but an answer for the [Closure Compiler dialect](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler) or even [JSDoc itself](https://jsdoc.app) would be insightful.

I tried (for TypeScript):

```js
try { throw new Error(); } catch (/** @type {Error} */ e) {/*...*/}
try { throw new Error(); } /** @param {Error} e*/ catch (e) {/*...*/}
/** @param {Error} e*/ try { throw new Error(); } catch (e) {/*...*/}
```

But without success. `e` has always type `any`. What would work is

```js
try { throw new Error(); } catch (_e) {
  /** @type {Error} */
  var e = _e;
  // ...
}
```

And the additional variable would be optimized away by closure compilers advanced mode, but I find that cumbersome and not optimal from a performance perspective (in a dev build) and hope there is a better way (i.e. one where I don't have to create an artificial variable just to annotate the right type).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try {throw new Error();} catch (/** @type {Error}*/whatIsMyType) {
  console.error(whatIsMyType.message);
}
```

Is valid according to [Closure Compiler](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540output_file_name%2520default.js%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540formatting%2520print_input_delimiter%252Cpretty_print%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520ADD%2520YOUR%2520CODE%2520HERE%250Atry%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520throw%2520new%2520Error()%253B%250A%257D%2520catch%2520(%252F**%2520%2540type%2520%257BError%257D*%252FwhatIsMyType)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520console.error(whatIsMyType.message)%253B%250A%257D).

I don't write much typescript, but I've poked around at a few sources and mostly don't see annotations at the `catch` level. The few I did [see](https://github.com/andrewhoi/HKM-QIS/blob/c92e3134c65961c462b917de50f12c0470600807/sequelize-typescript-examples/sequelize-express/test/services/product-service.ts#L25) looked like this;

```
try { throw new Error(); } catch (e: Error) {}
```

**Update:**

I think TypeScript has it right in refusing to guarantee a type for the `check` block. You can throw anything (intentionally or otherwise) within a `try` block so the compiler can't assure the catch is caught with the right type. In [a related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45379959/narrowing-down-error-type-in-catch) the solution is that you should check the  type in the `catch`:

```
try {
  throw new CustomError();
}
catch (err) {
  console.log('bing');
  if (err instanceof CustomError) {
    console.log(err.aPropThatIndeedExistsInCustomError); //works
    console.log(err.aPropThatDoesNotExistInCustomError); //error as expected
  } else {
    console.log(err); // this could still happen
  }
}
```

[credit for ☝](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45379959/narrowing-down-error-type-in-catch)

And I (and [Robert Martin](http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2017/01/13/TypesAndTests.html)) encourage this style of type checking even with strong types.

**Update 2**

I've re-written the example from above into Closure Compiler syntax, and I believe the point remains valid. Even if Closure lets you do the definition from the first example, you probably don't want to (or at least, not only that):

```
class CustomError extends Error {
  constructor() {
    super();
    /** @type {string} */
    this.aPropThatIndeedExistsInCustomError = '';
    throw new Error('Not so fast!');  // The evil part is here
  }
}


try {
  throw new CustomError();
}
catch (/**  @type {CustomError} */err) {
  console.log('bing');
  if (err instanceof CustomError) {
    console.log(err.aPropThatIndeedExistsInCustomError); //works
    console.log(err.aPropThatDoesNotExistInCustomError); //error as expected
  } else {
    console.log(err); // this could still happen
  }
}
```

[on closure-compiler.appspot](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F%252F%2520%253D%253DClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540compilation_level%2520ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540output_file_name%2520default.js%250A%252F%252F%2520%2540formatting%2520pretty_print%250A%252F%252F%2520%253D%253D%252FClosureCompiler%253D%253D%250A%250A%252F%252F%2520ADD%2520YOUR%2520CODE%2520HERE%250Aclass%2520CustomError%2520extends%2520Error%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520constructor()%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520super()%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520%252F**%2520%2540type%2520%257Bstring%257D%2520*%252F%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520this.aPropThatIndeedExistsInCustomError%2520%253D%2520''%253B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520throw%2520new%2520Error('Not%2520so%2520fast!')%253B%2520%2520%252F%252F%2520The%2520evil%2520part%2520is%2520here%250A%2520%2520%257D%250A%257D%250A%250A%250Atry%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520throw%2520new%2520CustomError()%253B%250A%257D%250Acatch%2520(%252F**%2520%2520%2540type%2520%257BCustomError%257D%2520*%252Ferr)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520console.log('bing')%253B%250A%2520%2520if%2520(err%2520instanceof%2520CustomError)%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520console.log(err.aPropThatIndeedExistsInCustomError)%253B%2520%252F%252Fworks%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520console.log(err.aPropThatDoesNotExistInCustomError)%253B%2520%252F%252Ferror%2520as%2520expected%250A%2520%2520%257D%2520else%2520%257B%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520console.log(err)%253B%2520%252F%252F%2520this%2520could%2520still%2520happen%250A%2520%2520%257D%250A%257D)

Comment: Catch clauses cannot have type annotations in TypeScript. The example is a promise catch handler which has different semantics since it's a function parameter.

Comment: Thanks *@Graham* for the Closure Compiler solution. *@Jake* so there is no way to do that with TypeScript? Sad, but understandable...