# Ignore certain error types in catch-clause in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, error-handling

I am sending an HTTP request to a REST endpoint using *Axios* and want to wrap any possible errors in a custom error that can be passed to the parent function where it will be logged:

- If there is an error in the *Axios* call, I am catching it within the same method and wrap it in my custom error type to add a meaningful description about where it happened
- If the HTTP request was successful, but there is an issue with the returned status code or data, I am throwing a custom error that should also be passed to the parent function

**So basically, what I want to do is catch only errors that are *NOT* of type *MyCustomError* locally.**

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45380550/4602192), there is no way to cherry-pick error types in try-catch-Blocks in TypeScript. That leaves me with this construct:

```
try {
  response = await axios.delete(deleteRequestURL, deleteRequestConfig);
  if (isRequestResponseSuccessful(response)) {
    return Promise.resolve(response.data);
  } else {
    throw new MyCustomError(`The DELETE request failed for some reason.`);
  }
} catch (e) {
  if (e instanceof MyCustomError) {
    throw e;
  } else {
    throw new MyCustomError(`Error while trying to reach the REST endpoint: ${e}`);
  }
}
```

IntelliJ is warning me about this, and rightfully so.

Is there a more elegant way to do this, without catching an error only to throw it again?

Obviously, I could just wrap my custom error within another custom error object and concatenate the error messages, but that would not be very elegant, either.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question.

You are quite right to feel a bit of unease about this. There's a good deal of info out there explaining why you should not really throw errors in a Typescript context, as throwing errors is not type safe. As [this article](https://benjaminjohnson.me/typesafe-errors-in-typescript) explains, the TS compiler is not clever enough to know that your `throw` are thrown inside `catch` blocks.

One pattern you could use to get around this is get your call to Axios to return an object, something like this:

```
type Result<T> = { status: 'Success' | 'Failure'; value: T | Error; }
```

Then instead of throwing from your Axios call you return a failed response with the error sttached (in case you want to handle it elsewhere). Conveniently, the above article fleshes this out in more detail for Axios; also note that this pattern is used by [Apollo GraphQL](https://www.apollographql.com/) which is no coincidence.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Good to know that throw-catch logic is to be avoided in TypeScript. I like the "Result" type approach, but how do you handle many nested calls where a failure on the lowest level (e.g. an Axios call) leads to quitting the whole procedure? I can pass on the error result objects to the parent methods, but it creates so much overhead to check for the result status after almost every call and I have to be careful which error message to pass on. Also, almost every involved method has a `Result` return type now. try-catch was way more clean and elegant with that regard...

Comment: Could you provide an example of the type of thing you mean? (And if you found this answer helpful please approve it)