# TypeScript noImplicitAny enabled implicit 'any' for Errors

Tags: typescript

The TypeScript application we are developing is making use of the following compiler option in tsconfig.json:

```
"noImplicitAny": true
```

However, we are trying to figure out how to handle Errors since, based upon this answer:

[How do you use typed errors in async catch()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42618089/how-do-you-use-typed-errors-in-async-catch)

as well as:

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8677#issuecomment-220385124

> We don't allow type annotations on catch clauses because there's
>   really no way to know what type an exception will have. You can throw
>   objects of any type and system generated exceptions (such as out of
>   memory exception) can technically happen at any time.

It appears errors cannot be typed.

We attempted to use:

```
"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
```

But that did not suppress the build error:

> Parameter 'error' implicitly has an 'any' type

We would prefer not to have that enabled in the first place since our goal is to avoid sloppy casting. Nevertheless, we have to have exception handling in our application. Is there another strategy or workaround that could be used to handle errors with the "noImplicitAny" option in TypeScript?

Comment: Post the code relating to the question. Please and thank you

Comment: Also the version of typescript you're working with.

Comment: TypeScript version 3.1 and the code is almost identical to what @shusson provided in his answer.

`service.method().catch((error) => {
  // handle the error
  ...
});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explicitly declare the error as `any`.

```js
service.method().catch((error: any) => {
  // handle the error
  ...
});
```

Now the intention is clear. The error can be any type and thus the code should handle it with care.

Comment: Thanks so much! I figured it was a simple solution I was overlooking.