# How to do try catch and finally statements in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, error-handling, try-catch

I have error in my project, and I need to handle this by using **try**, **catch** and **finally**.

I can use this in JavaScript but not in Typescript.

When I put ***Exception*** as argument in typescript **catch** statement, why it is not accepting this?

here is the code.

```js
private handling(argument: string): string {
    try {
        result= this.markLibrary(argument);
    }
    catch(e:Exception){
        result = e.Message;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I need an exception message here but I can't get. And I got the below error.

> Catch clause variable cannot have a type annotation.

Comment: **See Also**: [How do you use typed errors in async catch()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42618089/1366033)

Answer (score 160):

### Edit

Typescript 4.0 added the ability to specify `unknown` and `any` on catch variables ([Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36775)) And typescript 4.4 added the ability to make `unknown` the default on catch variables ([PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/41013)) using the `useUnknownInCatchVariables` flag.

With this flag  the following is now possible:

```
catch(e){
    result = e.message; // error under useUnknownInCatchVariables 
    if (typeof e === "string") {
        e.toUpperCase() // works, `e` narrowed to string
    } else if (e instanceof Error) {
        e.message // works, `e` narrowed to Error
    }
}
```

Specifying arbitrary types on catch variables is still not supported.

### Original answer

Typescript does not support annotations on the catch variable. There is a proposal to allow this but it is still being discussed (see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20024)).

Your only solution is to use a type assertion or an extra variable:

```
catch(_e){
    let e:Error= _e;
    result = e.message;
}

catch(e){
    result = (e as Error).message;
}
```

Unfortunately this will work as well and is completely unchecked:

```
catch(e){
    result = e.MessageUps;
}
```

**Note**

As you can read in the discussion on the proposal, in JS not everything that is thrown has to be an `Error` instance, so beware of this assumption.

Maybe tslint with `no-unsafe-any` would help catch this.

Answer (score 110):

With [TypeScript 4.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0/), you can set `unknown` as catch clause variable type:

> `unknown` is safer than `any` because it reminds us that we need to perform some sorts of type-checks before operating on our values. ([docs](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-0/#unknown-on-catch))

```
try {  /* ... */ }
catch (e: unknown) { // <-- note `e` has explicit `unknown` type
    e.message // errors
    if (typeof e === "string") {
        e.toUpperCase() // works, `e` narrowed to string
    } else if (e instanceof Error) {
        e.message // works, `e` narrowed to Error
    }
    // ... handle other error types 
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4JwngBA3hEPQCoIDpUQXCBfAUAYwENg8ALCACgFMAuCAVwDsBrBgewHcGBKaeTAHgC0giAGdKwCAANKUiMFbTGLDgzklKISjlixKyALaVRoggHNKfCJpCsQonboCWAMwrAwAB0qs3lgLyBEABEoqBODGbBPFCOurr6CgCqnt4gAMIE4uQ8cJjslmzsECrsADTSshBOohAEYuGRcdjWADbi1W5U1QxhBAx4Pm4AoiC2IDHN8fpGJuaWeRDsdkyiFTJyDARjHJQAJvKKo+PNuPGLqMgQJP17rZaswBog1jsvHt61OFhAA)

**Update:** [TypeScript 4.4](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-4.html#defaulting-to-the-unknown-type-in-catch-variables---useunknownincatchvariables) provides a config flag [`--useUnknownInCatchVariables`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/41013) to let catch-variables default to type `unknown`. This is also automatically enabled with the `--strict` flag.

Comment: Why is there to flag for `<Promise>.catch`?

Comment: @henroper mainly for backward-compatibility, I guess. If you have relied on error to be typed `any`, then now you probably would get a compile error.

Comment: Just a side note here, `catch (e: any)` can be helpful if you are passing all caught to a single error handler that is going to do more type parsing. I'd argue thats a safe and concise way to handle errors in traditional Class architecture.

Comment: err is unkown by default

Answer (score 22):

Can try this

```
try {...}
catch (e) {
    console.log((e as Error).message);
}
```

Also `any` type works as well.

```
try {...}
    catch (e:any) {
        console.log(e.message);
    }
```

But `instanceof` throw error.

```
try {...}
    catch (e) {
        console.log((e instanceof Error).message);
    }
```

Comment: why you cannot define   catch (e: Error)?

Answer (score 15):

Firstly, you need to define the `result` variable

```
let result;
```

Secondly, you can't define the type of e - as the message said, so in case you want to force the type of e, use

```
catch(e){
    result = (e as Exception).Message;
}
```

or

```
catch(e){
    result = (<Exception>e).Message;
}
```

Otherwise, it should still work because e will have the type as `any`

```
catch (e) {
    result = e.Message;
}
```

Comment: I thought you created that type already. Otherwise, it is not necessary, what do you see if you log e ```console.log(e)```

Comment: In javascript (and typescript), it is possible to throw anything.
`try {
  throw "just a string";
} catch (e) {
  /* This would fail, as string doesn't have a .message */
  const message = e.message;
}`
So don't cast to Exception. Use `instanceof` instead, as specified in the other answers.

Answer (score 4):

## Simple answer

```js
catch (e) {
  const error = e as <Your custom error type>;
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What works in my case is like this.
To print to terminal:

```
    catch(error){
      log('any_text', error as Error);
}
```

or call metod:

```
    catch(error){
       anything_here((error as Error).message),
}
```

Comment: This is like almost a legitimate answer, but you should put the whole try block in your snippet, and maybe explain why that works for you.