# Redux tool-kit error handling in axios request

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, redux-toolkit

In Thunk function I'm doing post http request, and in case of error I want to handle it => show messsage from server to user, like email already exist or else. But how do I properly define `type` of error in try{}catch{} syntax. With following code I have error in terminal
[image]

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import axios from "axios";
import { FormSignUp } from '../../types/FormSignUP';

export const signupUser = createAsyncThunk('user/signupUser', async (user: FormSignUp) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(API_URL, user);
    return response.data
  } catch (err: Error) {
    console.log(err.response.data)
  }
});
```

I understand that proper type of `err` in axios request is AxiosError. But with next code is another error.

```
import axios, { AxiosError } from "axios";

export const signupUser = createAsyncThunk('user/signupUser', async (user: FormSignUp) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(API_URL, user);
    return response.data
  } catch (err: AxiosError) {
    console.log(err.response.data)
  }
});
```

and here is an error
[image]

Edited:
So, this kind of works.

```
try {
    const response = await axios.post(API_URL, user);
    return response.data
  } catch (err) {
    if (axios.isAxiosError(err) && err.response) {
      console.log( err.response.data);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Typescript 4.0 added the ability to specify unknown and any on-catch variables (Issue) it can not do typecasting inside catch.

With this flag, the following is now possible:

[Reference this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54649623/13162928)

instead of this:

```js
try {
    const response = await axios.post(API_URL, user);
    return response.data
} catch (err) {
    if (axios.isAxiosError(err) && err.response) {
      console.log( err.response.data);
  }
}
```

You can do this

```js
try {
    const response = await axios.post(API_URL, user);
    return response.data
} catch (_err) {
   let err = (_err as AxiosError)
   // and you now got the error type
}
```