# 500 error and not details when running jest supertest with express

Tags: express, jestjs, serverless, acceptance-testing

I'm trying to add jest acceptance testing into an API repo (currently there are jest unit tests).  The app is serverless aws.  I'm working on getting a rough working p.o.c. API test against a staging url and I've put together this test file but it isn't working as expected and I don't have details to go on.  I'd like to know how to return more details for a failure or what I'm missing to get it to hit the route as expected.

I'm returning 500 errors, but no real extra details.  If I input an empty/invalid jwt token - still returns 500.  If I remove the expect(response.status).toEqual(200); it "passes" but the console.log("blah blah blah here" + response); fails to show the response (or the "blah blah blah" for that matter).  How can I return more details to see what I may be missing?  Or adjust my request so it successfully hits that route and returns a better response?

My auth_impersonation p.o.c. test

```
import { agent as request } from 'supertest';
import express = require('express');

describe('Impersonate SE merchant', () => {
  let app: express.Application = express();
  let jwtToken = 'string I'm putting in manually for now';

  it('returns a valid access token', async () => {
// within it block attempts here (below)

    const response = await request(app)
      .get('full staging url string here')
      .auth(jwtToken, {type: 'bearer'}); 
      console.log("blah blah blah here" + response);
    // expect(response.status).toEqual(200);
  })
});
```

Here's how the request looks in postman where the route works
[image]

Another go of the postman request, headers
[image]

Comment: You should be able to display an error message by `console.log`ing on the end-point tested (maybe use a `try ... catch`)

Comment: Made some edits to try and utilize try...catch based off this suggestion (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54649465/how-to-do-try-catch-and-finally-statements-in-typescript) but different error