# axios Error typescript, annotation must be 'any' or 'unknown' if?

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios

I got error of `Catch clause variable type annotation must be 'any' or 'unknown' if specified.ts(1196)`

with below code

```
import axios, { AxiosError } from "axios";
try {
        
    } catch(error: AxiosError) {
      throw Error(error);
    }
```

How to throw axios error in TS?

Comment: Please have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42618089/how-do-you-use-typed-errors-in-async-catch there it's saying that in the catch clause you can't have a type like you have it in your code

Comment: try this 
() : Promise<any | AxiosError > => {}

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Use AxiosError to cast error

```
import  { AxiosError } from 'axios';

catch (error) {
  const err = error as AxiosError
  console.log(err.response?.data)
}
```

Comment: The cast could fail? What would happen if cast fails?

Comment: With this you are skipping the Type part of TypeScript

Answer (score 58):

I would suggest to you, removing the error type like the following:

```
import axios from 'axios';

try {
  // do what you want with axios
  // axios.get('https://example.com/some-api');
} catch (error) {
  // check if the error was thrown from axios
  if (axios.isAxiosError(error)) {
    // do something
    // or just re-throw the error
    throw error;
  } else {
    // do something else
    // or creating a new error
    throw new Error('different error than axios');
  }
}
```

I just created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-tyyp8n?file=index.ts) for it.
And if you want to have a deeper look just have a look at this [article](https://fettblog.eu/typescript-typing-catch-clauses/)

Comment: I'm using typescript

Comment: and this works exactly like this in typescript :) if not for you, please be so kind and upload your `tsconfig.json` then I'll have a look at it

Comment: I use the default config

Comment: everyone has different ones, please share in your post ...

Comment: that's not the issue

Comment: As StackOverflow is not a chat forum, If you need help from someone, I would advise you to upload everything which is necessary to reproduce your error. Otherwise, people are not able to help you. The code from above is actually typescript code and works on my side.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/HFMLnbTn

Comment: It work for me, and I think its a better way than @Shaik Matheen

Answer (score 12):

You cannot write a specific annotation for the catch clause variable in typescript, this is because in javascript a catch clause will catch any exception that is thrown, not just exceptions of a specified type.

In typescript, if you want to catch just a specific type of exception, you have to catch whatever is thrown, check if it is the type of exception you want to handle, and if not, throw it again.

**meaning**: check if the error that is thrown is an axios error first, before doing anything.

```
try {
// do something
}catch (err) {
     // check if error is an axios error
     if (axios.isAxiosError(err)) {
                
      // console.log(err.response?.data)
      if (!err?.response) {
          console.log("No Server Response");
       } else if (err.response?.status === 400) {
         console.log("Missing Username or Password");
       } else if (err.response?.status === 401) {
         console.log("Unauthorized");
        } else {
        console.log("Login Failed");
      } 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The error could be of any type safer way to catch would be

```
try {
   // TODO :: API call
} catch (err) {
   if (error instanceof AxiosError) {
       // TODO :: handle it here
   } else {
      throw err
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You set the exception to `unknown` like so: `catch (err: unknown)` then you can use `instanceOf` to identify the errors or use `isAxiosError` to identify the AxiosError:

Using `instanceOf`:

```js
    import { AxiosError } from 'axios'

    ...

    function getTheAwesome () {
        try {
            // This is some method I need to call
            foo()
            
            // My axios client call
            await axios.get('/awesome')

            // This method can also throw an error
            await bar()
        } catch (err: unknown) {
            if (err instanceOf AxiosError) {
                // Handle the axios error
                // You can get the error response like this:
                if (err.response?.data) {
                    const errorResponse = err.response.data as MyErrorResponse
                }
            } else if (err instanceOf SomeOtherError) {
                // Handle the other errors that you expect from your other methods
            } else {
                // Handle everything else
            }
        }
    }
```

Using the Axios method `isAxiosError`:

```
    import { isAxiosError } from 'axios'
    ...
    try {
        ...
    } catch (err: unknown) {
        if (isAxiosError(err)) {
            // Handle the axios error
        } else if (err instanceOf SomeOtherError) {
            // Handle the other errors that you expect from your other methods
        } else {
            // Handle everything else
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
catch (error) {
                const err:any=error;
                alert(err.response.data)
            }
```

It works for me :)

Comment: The questions asks how to throw the error not call an alert function with its data.