# I Keep getting, 'Object is of type 'unknown'' error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, switch-statement

I'm trying to use a switch statement to notify the client side of any errors

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(response => {
    return response
}, (error: AxiosError) => {
    const {data, status} = error.response!;
    switch (status) {
        case 400:
            toast.error(data.title);
            break;
        case 401:
            toast.error(data.title);
            break;
        case 500:
            toast.error(data.title);
            break;
    
        default:
            break;
    }
    return Promise.reject(error.response);
})
```

But it complains about the 'data' variable, saying 'Object is of type 'unknown'. After doing some research they said I have to use a type guard, but I don't believe type guards are available for switch statements. Does anyone know how to rewrite this as an if statement or knows what I can do to fix this ?

Comment: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/3612#issuecomment-770224236

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69264472/axios-error-typescript-annotation-must-be-any-or-unknown-if

Answer (score 2):

Me too got same issues and found the solution. This is working for me.

```
const {data, status} = error.response!;
```

Working code:

```
const {data, status}:any = error.response!;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Does marking it as optional and defaulting the value get rid of the error?

```
const {data? = null, status} = error.response!;
```

Comment: nope :/ it says property null does not exist in AxiosResponse @Micky